# Error when building Cordova app using Crosswalk WebView plugin

Tags: android, cordova, build, crosswalk-runtime, build-error

When I try to build my Cordova app using Crosswalk WebView plugin I always get the following error:

> 1>  :processArmv7DebugResources FAILED

And also:

> You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project

I've opened Android SDK manager and I've the following SDKs already installed in my system: API Level 14, 15, 19 and 21.

Also, I've set minimum/target SDK version to 15.

Sadly, I can't figure out what's not being installed to fix the issue.

I'm using Cordova 5.1.1 and latest Crosswalk 1.2.0 plugin.

Also, I've tried to run `cordova build android --debug` to get any clue about what's missing in my development environment with no luck.

Comment: I am also getting the problem with crosswalk plugin in cordova app but don't get any help

Comment: @sanatshukla It's sad because I used to build this app in Cordova 3.x with no issues...

Comment: i used latest one before two months with no luck

Comment: @sanatshukla Check my auto-answer. I managed to solve it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally it's some issue with current Crosswalk 1.2.0 (stable) and they're about to roll out 1.3.0 stable in the next days.

For now, the issue can be fixed installing the plugin from GitHub directly:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview.git
```

This way, the project compiles successfully!

[Reference (Crosswalk JIRA)](https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-4546?focusedCommentId=35955&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-35955)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the Googles Intel Atom x86!
Solved my problem.

AVD-Settings:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y31W9.jpg

Cheers

Comment: Uhmm the issue is not when deploying. I'm just building the project. I mean, it's unrelated to *where* the package is going to be deployed later. Am I right?

Comment: Basically you are totally right, but when implementing the XWalk WebEngine, Cordova builds two types of apk. One is for x86 and one for Armv7.

Comment: But, you mean installing Google APIs for Intel Atom X86?

Comment: Or you may have a x86-based avd, and then you'll need an Armv7 avd.
Could need some more information about the problem, because I'm also using the XWalk Engine, without getting errors.

Comment: I'm not sure if we're understanding the issue at all. I'm not deploying to emulators but device. AVD is for VM images.